# How to broadcast a playlist from a Linux server?

Tags: linux, streaming

Recently I found an interesting service viloud.tv, which allows you to create online TV (videos go in order from the playlist, it looks like a live broadcast).

I have a server on Linux, I wanted to start broadcasting from OBS and VLC, but for this I need a very good server. Because they CODE the video and broadcast, but I do not need it, because I’m going to broadcast finished videos and there’s no reason to code them again.

Tell me how you can easily implement this. Thanks.

Comment: what does `easily` mean?

Comment: had in mind not quite difficult to configure, like OBS, it can be easily configured, but also does not require many resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember vlc executable being able to also broadcasting, using various protocolls including http, rtp, ... 
So simply copy your video files to the server, install vlc and find out how to open a broadcast video stream using vlc:

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Easy_Streaming/